# Div not clearing

Tags: css, html

Can anyone help me figure out why my background is not filling the entire height of the div?

The link is http://www.realfishin.com/___new

On the page it's the braggin board

If you click view source look for the comment

```
<!-- START BRAGGING BOARD -->
```

In the css file http://www.realfishin.com/___new/css/style.css

It's the last section "Braggin Board" ... the last 4-5 lines.

I'm stumped =/ Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: which background are you referring to?  The pattern surrounding the 'Bragging Board' text or the dark gradient layer in between the text and the videos?  If its the gradient layer you need to extend the height of the `bragBoard` div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put an height :

```
#bragBoard {
    height: 268px;
    padding: 5px;

}
```